# Invite feature in iOS, how to send a person's contact a message from within your app?

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering what cocoa framework (Swift) to use to pull up a list of contacts for a person (if they allow access) and then if they click on one of them, to open up messages to send a message to that friend with a link to the app.  I know Apple provides the contacts framework, but how to send the message itself?

Comment: I think he is asking how to SEND and SMS. Isnt that the `Message` framework. I haven't done it in a while. NOTE: It will open the messaging app. You cant send it in the background.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was after. Will try it!